# How to assign value to a variable based on IF sentences and the Alert? JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, output, alert

**How to assign value to a variable based on IF sentences and the Alert? in JavaScript**

Hi, I have this Code that works when I shows the results using Alerts on both cases, basically I evaluate the Visible Status of two controls using Jquery.

If pnlResultados is visible, shows: No Results or No hay Resultados
If PnlNoResultados is visible, shows: Results Available or Si Hay Resultados.

So this is my code:

```js
Dim Banner As String = "setDDLday();
var HayDescargaSiONo = 's';
function setDDLday() {
  setTimeout(VerificaResultados,100);
  function VerificaResultados() {
    if ($('#ctl00_MainContent_PnlNoResultados').css('display') != 'none') {
      HayDescargaSiONo ='No Hay Resultados';
    } else if ($('#ctl00_MainContent_PnlResultados').is(':visible')) {
      HayDescargaSiONo ='Si Hay Resultados';
    } else {
      setTimeout(VerificaResultados,100);
    };
  };
  alert (HayDescargaSiONo);
}"
```

When I put Alert in the next line after I assign a value It shows the result: Ex. "No Hay Resultados". But If I want to get the alert the value of **HayDescargaSiONo** Variable it said me: "Undefined" and also Is fired faster than the normal, so I can get a value.

What Am I doing wrong?

I want to assign a Value to the **HayDescargaSiONo** Variable.

If meets the first Condition, then Equals "No"
Else If meets the Second Condition, then Equals "Yes".

Comment: When asking for help with JavaScript code, quote the JavaScript code that will actually be run, not VB.Net code containing a string containing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to declare HayDescargaSiONo as `$HayDescargaSiONo` for global access.

```
setDDLday();
$HayDescargaSiONo = 's';
function setDDLday() {
    setTimeout(VerificaResultados,100);
    function VerificaResultados() {
        if ($('#ctl00_MainContent_PnlNoResultados').css('display') != 'none') {
            $HayDescargaSiONo ='No Hay Resultados';
        } else if ($('#ctl00_MainContent_PnlResultados').is(':visible')) {
            $HayDescargaSiONo ='Si Hay Resultados';
        } else {
            setTimeout(VerificaResultados,100);
        };
    };

    alert ($HayDescargaSiONo);
}
```